# In the below code: get_row_of_machine receiving mon_param as a parameter thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

mon_param is allocated memory by the main process invoking the thread function.
This function will be invoked by multiple threads.So, can I safely assume that it is thread safe as I am using only the variables on the stack?

```
struct table* get_row_of_machine(int row_num,struct mon_agent *mon_param)
{
    struct table *table_row = mon_param->s_table_rows;
    if(row_num < mon_param->total_states)
    {
        table_row = table_row + row_num;        
    }
    return table_row;
}


//in the main function code goes like this .... 
int main()
{
    int msg_type,ret;
    while(!s_interrupted)
    {

        inter_thread_pair = zsock_new(ZMQ_PAIR);
        if(inter_thread_pair != NULL)
            zsock_bind (inter_thread_pair, "inproc://zmq_main_pair");

            int ret_val = zmq_poll(&socket_items[0], 1, 0); // Do not POLL indefinitely.
            if(socket_items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
            {   
                char *msg = zstr_recv (inter_thread_pair); //
                if(msg != NULL)     
                {
                    struct mon_agent *mon_params;  
                    //This is where mon_params is getting its memory

                    mon_params = (struct mon_agent*)malloc(sizeof(struct mon_agent));
                    msg_type = get_msg_type(msg);

                    if(msg_type == /*will check for some message type here*/)
                    {
                         struct thread_sock_params *thd_sock = create_connect_pair_socket(thread_count);
                         // copy the contents of thread_sock_params and also the mon_params to this struct

                         struct thread_parameters parameters;
                         parameters.sock_params = thd_sock;
                         parameters.params = mon_params; //mon_params getting copid here.

                         //Every time I receive a particular message, I create a new thread and pass on the parameters.
                         //So, each thread gets its own mon_params memory allocated.


                     ret = pthread_create(&thread,NULL,monitoring_thread,(void*)&parameters);

                    and then it goes on like this.

                    }

                }    

            }   


        and the code continues..... there is a breakpoint somewhere down..
    }

}

void* mon_thread(void *data)
{

    //  First time data is sent as a function parameter and later will be received as messages.
    struct thread_parameters *th_param = (struct thread_parameters *)data;
    struct mon_agent *mon_params = th_param->params;

    zsock_t* thread_pair_client = zsock_new(ZMQ_PAIR);
    //printf("Value of socket is %s: \n",th_param->socket_ep);
    rc = zsock_connect(thread_pair_client,th_param->sock_params->socket_ep);
    if(rc == -1)
    {
      printf("zmq_connect failed in monitoring thread.\n");
    }

    while(!s_interrupted)
    {   
        int row;
        //logic to maintain the curent row.
        //also receive other messages from thread_pair_client  czmq socket.
        run_machine(row,mon_params);                

    }

}


void run_machine(int row_num, struct mon_agent *mon_params)
{   
    struct table* table_row = get_row_of_state_machine(row_num,mon_param);
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot assume that. `mon_param` is a local variable but not what it points to. So if another thread changes any of the values being pointed to you will have unpredictable results.

Comment: sorry.. for the type. It is actually mon_param and  not "mon".. I had to change it back due to a change i made to the return value.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The parameter name makes no difference to the fact that the code is not thread safe.

Comment: Whatever `current_row` is, it is not local.

Comment: BTW, this function is invoked from within a thread function handler.... IMO, each thread will have its own call stack and hence, the call to this function will receive the parameters passed to by a particular thread..is not my understanding correct? mon_param is not a global variable shared between the thread... are you telling me that the thread function itself has to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: Wether vane.. Sorry about that, that's my mistake..it will be passed to the function as a parameter..I edited that..

Comment: You haven't shown us what `mon_param` points to. If it points to something that only this thread uses then that's fine and the code is thread safe if used only in that way. But since we can't see that code we are only commenting in general (and in general the code is not thread safe). That's why it is always important to provide a [mcve] to avoid having to waste time extracting info from you bit by bit.

Comment: OMG another "something like my code" where we have to debug the "something like" before the *actual code* is posted. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: I shall take note of that from next time.. sorry about that..

Comment: "are functions receiving pointers as parameters thread-safe". BTW, the direct answer to that question is NO. But that's not what you are really asking anyway. You have constraints which that question alone does not capture so that question should be reworded.

Comment: Ok, I am really sorry that my posting was not upto the standards..this is my first post and hence the mistake.. nevertheless i shall take care from next time..

Answer (score 1):

In short, **no**.

The way to make parameters thread safe is by design.

There is no fool proof way to do this or a rule of thumb. If you know your codes design well enough and you *know* no other thread will access the same struct then it's possibly thread safe.

If you do know some other thread might try to access the struct you can use all sorts of synchronization primitives like [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion), [critical sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section), [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) or more generally [locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).